# Expanding an IDictionary<Key, IEnumerable<Value>>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I currently have a `Dictionary<Key, IEnumerable<Value>>`, and I want to expand this, so it would become a `Dictionary<Key, Value>`.

Doing this with a simple foreach loop is easy, but also messy:

```
var result = new List<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>();
foreach(var kvp in dict)
{
    foreach(var v in kvp.Value)
    {
        result.Add(new KeyValuePair<Key, Value>(kvp.Key, v));
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to convert this into a single LINQ query, and preferably using lambda syntax. (Currently not using expression syntax *anywhere* in the project, and don't feel like starting now)

Comment: This should blow up on you as Dictionaries only support one value per key. You need a MultiDictionary, and there is no such thing built into the base class libraries.

Comment: First of all, you have not tested the loop you are attempting to convert to a Single LINQ query. This will throw an "Key Already Exists" exception the first time it encounters a IEnumerable<Value> value with more than one member.

Comment: @Trillian @BolucPapuccuoglu Good point, I should probably change it to an ``IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>``

Comment: @Kippie Or to a `Lookup<T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add the same key twice but that would happen in your nested loop.

If you instead want to flatten it to a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>` as commented you can use `SelectMany`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> flattenedDict = dict
    .SelectMany(kv => 
        kv.Value.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kv.Key, v)));
```

Comment: Great, that does the job!

Answer (score 1):

How about this using LINQ inline:

```cs
var results = (from kvp in dict
                 from v in kvp.Value 
                 select new KeyValuePair<AddressType, ContractType>(kvp.Key, v))
                 .ToList();
```

Don't know about the lambda syntax, though.

Comment: Well, that works, though I'd **really** like it to be lambda, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use a `Lookup<T>` as it supports multiple keys per value,

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
var lookUp = dictionary
    .SelectMany(pair => pair.Value
        .Select(value => new { Key = pair.Key, Value = value }))
    .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```